# How to change a specific cell's value in a DataGrid to one located in the DataGrid's ContextMenu using MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, datagrid, contextmenu

I have a DataGrid that is bound to a IList and displays a list of type Equipment. I next created a ContextMenu that is part of the DataGrid that won't have commands but alternative names that I can use. What I want to do next is select any individual cell in the DataGrid, right click and choose a new name in the context menu and replace the current value in the Data grid with current tag/value in the context menu. I am doing this using the MVVM pattern so using the code behind in the MainWindow.xaml.cs is NOT a valid option.

How I implemented my DataGrid and got the data posted.

```
MainWindow.xaml
{
<DataGrid Background="Gray" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" Grid.ColumnSpan="9" Grid.RowSpan"2" Name="equipmentGrid" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EquipmentList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Equip Key" Binding="{Binding EquipKey}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Equip Name" Binding="{Binding EquipName}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How I implemented my ContextMenu

```
EquipmentIdFixViewModel
{
     private IList<Emitter> Emitters;
      ....
      public ICommand CreateContextMenuCommand
        {
          {
            get
               {
                  if(this._createContextMenuCommand == null)
                      {
                       this._createContextMenuCommand = new RelayCommand(a => this.CreateContextMenu(), p => this.CheckCondition());
                       return this._createContextCommand;
                      }
                  return this._createContextMenuCommand;
                }
            set
     {
            _this._createContextCommand = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CreateContextMenuCommand");
     }
  }
public ContextMenu EmitterContextMenu
{
 get{return _emitterContextMenu;}
 set{_emitterContextMenu = value; OnPropertyChanged("EmitterContextMenu");}
}
public void CreateContextMenu()
{
  var contextMenu = new ContextMenu()
  Emitters = new EmitterList().GetAll();
  foreach (Emitter in  Emitters)
  {
    MenuItem item = new MenuIten();
    item.Header = emitter.EmitterName;
    item.Tag = emitter;
    item.Click += MenuItem_Click
    contextMenu.Items.Add(item);
  }
   EmitterContextMenu = contextMenu;
}

private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    var myObj = (Emitter)((MenuItem)sender).Tag;
    Equipment et = this._grid.SelectedItem as Equipment; //Doesn't work.Ends up being null. Can't figure out how to capture the data from the DataGrid
    et.EquipKey = myObj.EmitterName;
  }
}
```

What happens is that et is null. How do I get a reference to the information that is presented in the DataGrid?